# Counting pages in each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I made a function that counts the number of pages. At least I thought so... It is counting the number of worksheets... If a worksheet has more than one page it does not count it...
Does anyone have any idea how to count page of a workbook?
I cant use excel page count function because I am using a macro to fill data of footer and header.

```
Function Showpage()
    Application.Volatile
    Showpage = ActiveSheet.Index & "/" & Worksheets.Count
End Function
```

that is the code I use for counting pages...

Comment: welcome to SO. In order to facilitate answering your question, could you paste your code?

Comment: also, could you clarify " I cant use excel page count function because I am using a macro to full data of footer and header." ?

Comment: Hello, i am sorry i forgot to pase  the code.. i added it to the post

As for the data of header and footer. I need to pull METADATA from cells to header and footer.

Comment: Do you have any page breaks set manually? If not then, assuming you know how many rows you get to a page, you could just count rows in each sheet, divide by that number and thus get pages per sheet, add them up to get a total?

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
Sub Test()
Dim totPages    As Integer

totPages = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count
MsgBox "The Number Of Print Pages On The Worksheet Is " & totPages
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A formula that will find you the number of pages that will be printed can be written using the ExecuteExcel4Macro method.

```
Showpage = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
```

*Note:* This formula counts like a printer would count it, and therefore only works for pages with data. If pages are added manually but are blank, they will not be counted.